# Massive reduction in wifi speed in 1 meter

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, connection, internet-connection, airport

When I'm sitting on my desk the speed and reliability of my wifi is horrible but if I move my laptop 1 meter towards the source (trough open air) it gets much better (but now it's no longer on my desk). Does anybody have a clue of how my wifi signal becomes so much stronger, using Istumbler I saw no extra noise or significant signal reduction just the ping starts shoots up from 40-50 towards 200-2000 (and even a complete loss of internet connection). Does anybody know a solution?

By the way this is an n protocol 5 ghz network.

Comment: 5 GHz tend to degrade much easier with obstructions, but that is pretty much overkill for that in this case :) Do you use an antenna? Is your transmitting power set to max in settings?

Comment: Waves and their propagation capabilities is a really tough matter. There is "something" (another conflicting wave, something metallic?) that disturbs the waves at this point. One possible solution would be to move the access point.

Comment: Well I have moved the station in the past but that didn't work, wouldn't a program like Istumbler detect it if there was another wave nearby? There is a large metal structure around a 80 cm bellow my position but the wave is already coming from a position above my current one (the access point is placed on top of a bookshelf 2 meters from the ground). I use the internal antena from my macbook (late 2011 model).

Comment: does the signal change in all directions? removing a wall mirror once did wonders for my wireless signal.

Comment: There is a kind of line orthogonal to my wireless (around 12 meters away from the source) after which it drops quite strongly.